# Vue-loader dynamic list of components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-loader

I am quite new to Vue.js and got stuck at a problem that shouldn't be too hard to solve: I have a single file component (.vue) that is supposed to view/manage a dynamic list of another single file component via JS.

My approach is this:

```
<script>
import Event from './DayView/Event'
export default {
  components: {
    Event
  },
  props: ['day']
}

const $ = window.$ = require('jquery')
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#day-view').append(new Event())
})
</script>
```

This results in the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__DayView_Event___default.a is not a constructor
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `$('#day-view')[0]` ? `$('#day-view')` returns one single element.

Comment: You're right, I sometimes get confused there. Doesn't change anything with the problem though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem (which isn't neccessarily mounting new objects). As `DayView` is supposed to view a list of `Event`s, using a list of objects combined with `v-for` did the trick for me:

```
<template>
  <div id="day-view">
    [...]
    <event v-for="event in events" :event="event"></event>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Event from './DayView/Event'

let events = []

export default {
  components: {
    Event
  },
  data () {
    return {
      events: events
    }
  }
}

const $ = window.$ = require('jquery')
$(document).ready(function () {
  events.push({start: '540', end: '630'})
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/

```
<template><div><event /></div></template>
<script>
import Event from './DayView/Event'
export default {
  components: {
    Event
  },
  props: ['day']
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't solve my problem. I know this method (this is how I use DayView in other components). The question is how to add a component via JS (e.g. in a callable function).

Comment: sounds like you want to dynamically set the mount point then?
 https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/254#issuecomment-122276887